# Jquery: Adding Pages to a Document feature behaving wierdly when navigating from other pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, navigation

I have a simple collection of web pages written using Jquery mobile framework. The list of pages are as follows:

Main.html. This page consists of a link to another page called dummy.html.

The dummy.html is as follows:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
  <div data-role="header">
      <h1>HOD</h1>
   </div>

           <ul data-role="listview">
             <li><a href="#glug">Welcome to GLUG MEET</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">New trends in CS</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
            </ul> 

 </div>


<div id="glug" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>GLUG</h1>
     </div>
      <div>
        <div class="lcontainer">
            <img src="glug.png">
              <div>
               <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button"
                data-inline=true data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
              </div>
            </div>             
            <div class="productData">
                All of you DO attend glug meet today
                <div><b>At 04:00 PM</b></div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Suppose if I open dummy.html and click on `Welcome to GLUG MEET` the page with `id glug` opens without any fuss. But If I navigate from main.html to dummy.html and then click on `Welcome to GLUG MEET` the page with `id glug` refuses to open. I have to refresh dummy.html to open page with `id glug`.

Why is this happening. I tried it running from Apache web server and also Aptana studio. By pressing ctrl + f11 but nothing works.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Its working just fine. Do you have any JavaScript functions implemented?

I tried on my machine it works fine without any fuzz.

Here is an example <kbd>**[Live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/uEkC9/)**</kbd>

if you have any JS functions make sure to wrap them inside

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#yourPageID', function(){
 // your code goes here
});
```

Comment: Sorry! My internet connection got messed up could not reply

Comment: I dont and it is not working. Is there any way I can show you the video of this?

Comment: if you don't mind email me the code I'll check it and tell you.

Comment: Should I ask Shiva and Parvathi for your mail ID?? Or Arjuna Ranatunga :-). I dont have your mail id :)

Comment: I got it. Now delete your comment which has your email id.

Comment: I did not get any email back from you

Comment: I checked your code. Its working just fine for me. Did you host it in IIS or in your linux server? if you run it locally JQM pages won't work properly.

Comment: Mayu I did mail you and I did not get any response

Comment: I replied your email. don't knw why u didn't receive the reply.